# Multiple users of SVN with single ssh account

Tags: svn, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to use multiple svn authors for single hosting ssh account. I followed tricks from `http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/ssh-tricks` for tunnel-users but it is still showing same author as my hosting ssh account username. I have also checked that SVN version must be newer to 1.0.x to make it work for tunnel-users.

**UPDATE**

What I followed:

1. First I have taken the key from my hosting account `id_rsa`
2. Then I used `PuttyGen` to import and extracted the private key.
3. After that I created a `session` in Putty with my complete
   domain(.com/.net etc) and attached the private key in SSH->AUTH also
   I added my hosting account username in `data` for Auto-login.
4. For verification I checked the session and it worked without asking
   any password.
5. Now I created a copy of my `id_rsa` key in `~/.ssh` dir as
   `authorized_keys` which is required by `svnserve`
6. Then I appended a line `command="~/bin/svnserve -t -r ~/svn
   --tunnel-user=makki",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty
   ssh-rsa AAfagd..... makki@domain.com`
7. Now when all ready I created a repo on server with `svnadmin create
   myrepo`
8. I checked out with `svn+ssh://mydomain.com/home/svn/myrepo` and it
   successfully checked out But now when I commit it shows author as my
   ssh account not `makki` as I mentioned in the line which I appended
   in `authorized_keys` file.

Please guide what I am missing in the flow...

**authorized_keys content**

line#1 ssh-rsa AAAAB3..........

line#2 command="~/bin/svnserve -t -r ~/svn --tunnel-user=makki",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not working you must be missing the --tunnel-user option in your command or you're not using a unique key for the user.

From the [SSH configuration section of the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks):

> It's also possible to have multiple users share a single account.
>   **Instead of creating a separate system account for each user, generate
>   a public/private key pair for each person.** Then place each public key
>   into the authorized_keys file, one per line, and use the --tunnel-user
>   option:
>
> command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=harry" TYPE1 KEY1
>   harry@example.com
>     command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=sally" TYPE2
>   KEY2 sally@example.com
>
> This example allows both Harry and Sally to connect to the same
>   account via public key authentication. Each of them has a custom
>   command that will be executed; the --tunnel-user option tells svnserve
>   to assume that the named argument is the authenticated user. **Without
>   --tunnel-user, it would appear as though all commits were coming from the one shared system account**.

Emphasis mine.

Based on your update to the question, it looks to me like you're reusing a key.  Instead you should be generating a unique key for each user.  Typically, how this would work is the user would generate their own key and then give you the public key which you'd add.  If the key already exists in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file then I suspect the most permissive entry will apply.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, Please check the flow I added in my question and see if I am doing it correctly

Comment: I've updated my question, I believe you aren't using a unique key based on what you posted.

Comment: Hmmm... I was also thinking in that direction.. but it looks that `svnserve` is not looking for the public key which I have appended in my `authorized_keys` file. I have added the content of my `authorized_keys` file from server, please check if the entries are correct.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that line #1 has the same key as in line #2, causing `sshd` to simply use the first one?

In any case, a couple of debugging pointers:

1. On the server side, you can use the `--log-file` option to `svnserve` to debug if it is even getting invoked

   ```
   command="~/bin/svnserve -t -r ~/svn --tunnel-user=makki --log-file /home/makki/svnserve.log",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty
   ```

   Now, if you `tail -f /home/makki/svnserve.log`, you should see some activity if the svn tunnels through svnserve as expected.
2. On the client side, modify the Subversion `config` file to specify that `ssh` should log at verbose level (`-v` option without `-q`). That has helped me many a time to understand the root cause!

Comment: There isn't enough of the key to be sure.  He's only got the common prefix that all keys share included (well the second key includes a bit that differs based on key type, but it's still nothing unique enough to draw any conclusions).  But the log file suggestion is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I agree! I changed the language to reflect that I am guessing.